# Firebase realtime db + nodejs (auth.uid === $uid rule)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to use fetch to access /userInfo collection and I have the following rules in firebase:

```
"rules": {
    "userInfo": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    }
```

I was trying to extend the default user profile and saw that I need to create collection and add the additional data there so my collection is "userInfo".

Now I am trying to restrict user of fetching other users information so he cannot do something like:

```
fetch(db.firebaseio.com/userInfo.json)
```

and get all the information about all users.

So the problem is when the rule is "auth !== null" I can simply add "?auth=" + token at the end of the url to auth, but it doesn't work the same way for auth.uid.

I wonder what should be the query parameter when sending the request so I can tell to firebase what my user.uid is?

Attaching postman screenshot for better understanding of the problem:
[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GUL8.png)

Attaching also DB struct from Firebase:
[DB Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9TwO.png)

Request with token:
[Postman request with token also gives permission denied for this rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ympnF.png)

Comment: You don't tell firebase what your user id is, firebase knows who you are based on your auth token.

Comment: @tkausl okay, if so why the request returns permission denied when I use token to auth?

Comment: Firebase expects the token to be in [`access_token`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-param-auth), not in `auth`.

Comment: If you pass the auth parameter correctly, you don't need to specify anything else for the rules to know the UID.  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what you're doing to get the user token and pass it.

Comment: @tkausl Actually, you do pass an auth parameter, as described in the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#authenticate_with_an_id_token

Comment: @DougStevenson Added additional details, I am pretty sure that I am passing the auth param corectly, check the screenshot "request with token"

Comment: The problem is that we can't validate for ourselves that you've passed a correct token.

Comment: Okay, that the same passing method of the token works with rule auth !== null, so the problem should not be in the passing.